# What can I do while I wait for the TeamCity Git plugin to get pre-tested commit support?

Tags: git, teamcity

I'm brand new to CI.  I want to submit my code changes to TeamCity and have it run all the tests and, if they pass, commit to source.  However, I use Git and it looks like the Git plugin doesn't have support for pre-tested commits or personal builds yet.

If you use Git and TeamCity, how do you deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [already supported](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-9284) in the upcoming TeamCity 5.0 for IntelliJ IDEA 9.0. For Visual Studio support [watch/vote the issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-9100).

TeamCity 5.0 also has a feature to [perform remote runs from the command line tool](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TW/Darjeeling+EAP+Release+Notes+%28build+10307%29) if your IDE is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not yet there.

Yes, you have remote runs, but you don't have Teamcity+Intellij IDEA pre-tested, automated commits for distributed version control systems as for today.

All you can do is a pre-tested commit with the command-line tool (mentioned above) and the pre-commit/receive hook on git repository you are trying to commit to.